# Can anyone recommend me a book, which explains the general eigenvalue problem and the general rayleigh quotient in details?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am not  familiar with the knowledge about the general eigenvalue problem and the general rayleigh quotient in algebra? Can anyone recommend a book to me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try "Numerical Methods for Large Eigenvalue Problems: Revised Edition" by Yousef Saad which is a good book on this subject.